# I need to read a file written in TypeScript (An Angular Module) and programatically add code to the original file. Any ideas on how can I do it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

This is the app.module.ts file I want to read (Written In TypeScript).

```
    import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Then, basically I want to programatically add another component like this:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { ShowsComponent }      from './shows/shows.component';//** NEW LINE
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent },
  { path: 'shows', component: ShowsComponent }//** New Line
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

So, the program would receive the original file as input and then when finish the original file would be modified with the new code. The "component" to be added can be received as a parameter.

How would you go about solving this?

PD: I want to do it so I detect the symbols properly. I mean, the code has to work as long as the syntax of the target TS file is valid.

PD2: I've been checking the Compiler Api
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the TypeScript compiler, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

Comment: Are you working in browser?

Comment: It seems you can just read the file into a string in node.js and then use a regex to find the line before where you want to insert the new content.  Once you have the index, you can use `.slice()` to create a new string that consists of the content before your insertion point, your new content and the content after the insertion point.  Then, write out the new string to a file.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys. Yes, I've been checking the compiler option yurzui. And jfriend, that would certainly be an option but I need to ensure it will work no matter the code inside of the TypeScript file or the name of the variables.

Comment: So, do your latest additions to your question mean you are saying you have to actually interpret the code?

Comment: How do you know where to insert it?   You have to be looking for something in particular, right?  What is it that you're looking for that indicates where the new content should be inserted?  You can't solve this problem if you ignore all names of everything.  Then, there's no way to know what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes jfriend00, I want this to work no matter the name of the symbols. Im trying to build a scaffolding tool to quickly generate crud screens.

Comment: This is an unsolvable problem if you don't specify some constraints on what you're looking for to know where to insert the new content.  It's completely unconstrained.  You have to pick some indicator for where to put the new content.

Comment: Well I have to add two things, 1) import { ShowsComponent }      from './shows/shows.component';//** NEW LINE 2) Then I have to modify "routes" array of type "Routes" and add " { path: 'shows', component: ShowsComponent }//** New Line". Ideally this would work even if the name of the variable is not "routes".

Comment: Then, describe an algorithm in words that explains how you detect where to put these.  If you're not going to look for any particular name, then you have to look for some type of pattern that some piece of code can recognize.  For the `import` statement, can't it just go anywhere at the top of file where other imports are?  Is there any reason it has to go exactly where you show it?

Comment: @RodNavarro The idiomatic tool for that that allows to integrate with Angular CLI is https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/schematics . There's not much resources to learn about it, I'd suggest to check *dependents* section at NPM for some examples. Considering that you need to modify existing files, you will likely end up parsing TS with ng-ast or something.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with typescript compiler API.

Let's say we add import at the end of all other imports and also add route at the end of all other routes.

Here's a **[simplified version](https://ng-run.com/edit/LlwHikje8Pjk44SqgjPK?layout=1&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**. You can improve it if:

- you need to check if there is already added route.
- or for instance if there is added import path then we do not need to add new import but rather add clause to exising.

or something else depending on your demands.

```
interface Replacement {
  atPosition: number;
  toInsert: string;
}

function replace(content: string) {
  const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile('', content, ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, true);

  const replacements: Replacement[] = [
    addRoute({ path: 'shows', component: 'ShowsComponent' }, sourceFile),
    addImport({ name: 'ShowsComponent', path: './shows/shows.component'}, sourceFile)
  ]

  for (const replacement of replacements) {
    content = content.substring(0, replacement.atPosition) + replacement.toInsert + content.substring(replacement.atPosition);
  }

  return content;
}

function addRoute(route: { path: string, component: string }, sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): Replacement {
  const routesDefinition = getRoutesArrayNode(sourceFile);
  const routes = findNodes(routesDefinition, ts.SyntaxKind.ObjectLiteralExpression);

  const toInsert = `,\n  { path: '${route.path}', component: ${route.component} }`;
  return insertToTheEnd(routes, toInsert);
}

function addImport(toImport: { name: string, path: string }, sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): Replacement {
  const allImports = findNodes(sourceFile, ts.SyntaxKind.ImportDeclaration);

  const toInsert = `\nimport { ${toImport.name} } from '${toImport.path}';`;
  return insertToTheEnd(allImports, toInsert);;
}

function insertToTheEnd(nodes: any[], toInsert: string): Replacement {
  const lastItem = nodes.sort((first: ts.Node, second: ts.Node): number => first.getStart() - second.getStart()).pop();
  const atPosition: number = lastItem.getEnd();

  return { atPosition, toInsert };
}

function getRoutesArrayNode(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): ts.Node {
  let result: ts.Node | null = null;
  ts.forEachChild(sourceFile, (node) => {
    if (node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.VariableStatement) {
      const variableStatement = <ts.VariableStatement>node;
      for (const variableDeclaration of variableStatement.declarationList.declarations) {
        if (variableDeclaration.name.kind == ts.SyntaxKind.Identifier && variableDeclaration.initializer) {
          const initializerNode = variableDeclaration.initializer;
          if (initializerNode.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ArrayLiteralExpression) {
            if (isRoutesArray(variableDeclaration)) {
              result = initializerNode;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return result;
}

function isRoutesArray(node: ts.Node): boolean {
  let result = false;
  ts.forEachChild(node, child => {
    if (child.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.TypeReference) {
      const typeReferenceNode = <ts.TypeReferenceNode>child;
      const typeNameNode = typeReferenceNode.typeName;
      if (typeNameNode.text === 'Routes') {
        result = true;
      }
    }
  });
  return result;
}


function findNodes(node: ts.Node, kind: ts.SyntaxKind): any[] {
  const arr: any[] = [];
  if (node.kind === kind) {
    arr.push(node);
  }

  for (const child of node.getChildren()) {
    findNodes(child, kind).forEach(node => {
      arr.push(node);
    });
  }

  return arr;
}
```

These links might be also helpful for you:

- https://github.com/angular/devkit/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/utility/ast-utils.ts
- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2c2b62f45f29e7658028d85be5a26db812c0525d/packages/compiler-cli/src/metadata/evaluator.ts#L253

**P.S.** If you're on node.js then I suppose you know how work with `fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile` :)